# Aaccessing button properties from another jsp file

Tags: html, jsp, button, dom-events

I have disabled button in a.html and some xyz button in b.html.
When the xyz button in b.html is clicked then the disabled button in a.html should get enabled.

I have been trying this for two days but am not getting anywhere. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you loading `a.html` inside `b.html` or vice-versa . How are they linked ?

Comment: you should provide the code you have tried. An explanation as to what doesn't work as expected and any error messages (if any) that showed up.

Comment: a.html is the student interface and b.html is the teacher interface. when teacher clicks his button then the student's button should get enabled. i did not do any loading i just created 2 html files.

Comment: @SMadhu if both are different files without any relation you cant disable it directly. instead you can maintain a flag variable in the database of the student to track the info . enable and dis-able based on its value

Comment: @San Krish thank you.......it worked with flag variable in the database......

Comment: But i would like to know that is there any other way so that i can create one jsp file in which i can create relation between both html files....

Comment: @SMadhu I dont there is a way , think of the distributed environment where you will have multiple logins . so you need to take it to the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both are different files without any relation you cant disable it directly. instead you can maintain a flag variable in the database of the student to track the info . enable and dis-able based on its value.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just plain html pages, you can use `jQuery/ JavaScript` to do this. Here is a simple example:

a.html:

```
<body>
  <input id="aButton" type="button" value="A Button">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var enableAButton=getUrlParameter("enable");

        if(enableAButton == "true"){
            $('#aButton').prop('disabled', false);
        }else{
            $('#aButton').prop('disabled', true);//disabled by default
        }
    });

    function getUrlParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    } 
  </script>
</body>
```

b.html:

```
<body>
  <input id="bButton" type="button" value="B Button">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#bButton").click(function(){
        window.location.href="a.html?enable=true"
    });
  </script>
</body>
```